# Change the colour of the underline in ssrs reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, underline, text-decorations

Can you tell me a way to change the color of the underline property in SQL reports.

I have the following expression which does not work obviously:

```
=Format(Color:"Blue", "Underline")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the color of the **underline** on it's own in **SSRS**. The underline color would have the color of the FONT.

You can use the **BorderColor.Bottom** property of a text box to set any color using a value (Red or a hex value #FF0000) or an expression:

```
=IIF(FIELDS.X.VALUE = "X", "Blue", "Red")
```

Set the BorderStyle.Bottom to **Solid** (or anything but None) to make it visible.